# PDO ODBC error just resets connection

Tags: apache-2.2, php, odbc, pdo, cakephp

Trying to write an [ODBC PDO driver for CakePHP](https://gist.github.com/shrimpwagon/5207702). Seems like I get closer and closer however whenever a PDO function is called that it doesn't like the connection just gets reset immediately and I'm not able to get any error information whatsoever. I'm thinking this could be a possible config setting but I can't find anything. I dunno if this will help but here is the particular snippet I'm working with:

```
public function fetchResult() {
    debug($this->_result);
    if ($row = $this->_result->fetch()) { // ### HERE IS WHERE IT RESETS ###
        debug($this->_connection->errorInfo());
        exit;
        $resultRow = array();
        foreach ($this->map as $col => $meta) {
            list($table, $column, $type) = $meta;
            if ($table === 0 && $column === self::ROW_COUNTER) {
                continue;
            }
            $resultRow[$table][$column] = $row[$col];
            if ($type === 'boolean' && !is_null($row[$col])) {
                $resultRow[$table][$column] = $this->boolean($resultRow[$table][$column]);
            }
        }
        return $resultRow;
    }
    $this->_result->closeCursor();
    return false;
}
```

The only difference between this method and the [original CakePHP fetchResult function](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/source-class-Sqlserver.html#591-614) is that I'm not passing in the `PDO::FETCH_NUM` argument but either way still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

There are deeper issues.

I'm certain this is a bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64483

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar issue.  Try checking your error logs for:

> [notice] child pid 16759 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

I'm not trying to use PDO, but using ODBC I get crashes too.  It only happens when an SQL statement returns null.  People have suggested using COALESCE(field, '') to return empty strings, but that is a ridiculous workaround.  Also there is a bug in PHP that relates to this as well, looks like 5.3.11 is when the null bug was corrected.  My issue now seems to be a mismatch of 64-bit & 32-bit softwares.  Another thing worth noting is that the bugs reported were 64-bit only.

Links:

[LAMP using ODBC to DB2](https://serverfault.com/questions/490202/lamp-using-odbc-to-db2)

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59405

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54007

Comment: OMG! "AH00052: child pid 5808 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)". Also getting "zend_mm_heap corrupted"

Comment: OK so for starters check the output of phpinfo(), specifically PHP version. Also compare odbc.ini (in /etc/unixODBC?) to phpinfo() (ctrl+f for odbc) and make sure you don't have a 32/64-bit mismatch, and I'll assume that something somewhere is 64-bit (straight 32-bit seems to work no problem).  Also read bug 54007's comments 2nd from the end: "It seems that when field is null the ODBC driver return the pointer of somewhere in the memory..." and all I could think was, huh?  Lastly run a query that is guaranteed to not return any null fields and see if that works.

Comment: Everything on my end is 32 bit for sure.

Comment: Weird....  Well a few questions then, what is the type of database you're connecting to?  And what about queries that specifically do and don't return null fields?

Comment: I'm connecting to a MSSQL Server 2005 via ODBC/FreeTDS. I'm 100% certain that the query I'm running works. I've tried it independently in Access. I don't think it has to do with nulls. Check out the link to the php bugs that I posted in the above answer.

Comment: I agree it sounds similar but unrelated.  I'm sure both are bugs, and I'm guessing your situation is a new bug.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was cause my db includes accented non US text.
Change my selects to "SELECT field **Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI** FROM database WHERE clauses" and works!

Comment: Oh, nice, thank you! I don't know if I will ever deal with this problem again but good to know. If you are sure you have solved the problem then I will accept this as the answer.